# Eclipse plugin: Return affected class from IResourceChangeListener

Tags: java, eclipse, class, eclipse-plugin, listener

I do have a `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for changes in the workspace. However I was not able to return only the class which triggered the `IResourceChangeEvent`.

This is, what I currently have:

```
public class ResourceChangeListener implements IResourceChangeListener {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        IResourceDelta[] allChanges = event.getDelta().getAffectedChildren();

        for(IResourceDelta delta : allChanges) {
            // only check projects when there are actual changes (4 = CHANGED)
            if(delta.getKind() == 4) {
                try {
                    IPackageFragment[] packages = JavaCore.create(delta.getResource().getProject()).getPackageFragments();
                    IPackageFragment myPackage = null;

                    // get current project package
                    for(IPackageFragment currentPackage : packages) {
                        if(currentPackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {
                            myPackage = currentPackage;
                        }
                    }

                    // get all compilation units from package and parse them for new achievements
                    ICompilationUnit[] units = myPackage.getCompilationUnits();
                    for(ICompilationUnit unit : units) {
                        // do something with ICompilationUnits
                    }
                }
                catch (JavaModelException e) {
                    // catch exception here
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This attempt returns the whole package which is affected. Thus I can only loop over all of the ICompilationUnits in it.

In contrast to that, my goal is to **get the class where the actual change has happened**. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: delta.getResource() will return you an `IFile` when a file is changed you should be able to find the compilation units from that.

Comment: @greg-449 I already tried this. The return value always is `P/asd`. I think this stands for "Project/<ProjectName>". Do you have any idea how to resolve `getResource()` back to the actual file?

Comment: Maybe this is because I add the listener like this: `workspace.addResourceChangeListener(new ResourceChangeListener(), IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD);`?

Comment: You have to recurse through the children of the delta, or use the `accept` method to call an `IResourceDeltaVisitor` for each item in the delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to greg, I was able to get a solution.

My initial class now looks like this:

```
public class ResourceChangeListener implements IResourceChangeListener {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        IResourceDelta[] allChanges = event.getDelta().getAffectedChildren();

        for(IResourceDelta delta : allChanges) {
            if(delta.getKind() == 4) {  // only check projects when there are actual changes (4 = CHANGED)
                try {
                    // visits resource deltas
                    ResourceDeltaVisitor resourceDeltaVisitor = new ResourceDeltaVisitor();
                    delta.accept(resourceDeltaVisitor);
                    ArrayList<IResource> changedClasses = resourceDeltaVisitor.getChangedResources();

                    for(IResource changedClass : changedClasses) {
                        ICompilationUnit iCompilationUnit = (ICompilationUnit)JavaCore.create(changedClass);
                        // do something with ICompilationUnits...
                    }
                }
                catch (CoreException e1) {
                    // catch exception here
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My `ResourceDeltaVisitor`  class looks like this:

```
public class ResourceDeltaVisitor implements IResourceDeltaVisitor {

    private ArrayList<IResource> changedClasses = new ArrayList<IResource>();

    public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) {
        IResource res = delta.getResource();
        if(res.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
            addResource(res);
        }
        return true; // visit the children
    }

    public ArrayList<IResource> getChangedResources() {
        return changedClasses;
    }

    private void addResource(IResource res) {
        changedClasses.add(res);
    }
}
```

This is not the best solution, but it works for me.